# Knockout binding is undefined for click

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model Which has to be attached to a click event of an `<li>` tag. Here is the viewmodel and markup

```
  var viewModel =
    {
        Folders: ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'],
        SelectedFolder: ko.observable('Inbox'),
        chosenFolderId: ko.observable(),
        navigate: function () {
            self.chosenFolderId(folder);               
        }
    };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And the markup is

```
   <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix" data-bind="foreach:Folders">
                @*<li data-bind="css:{active: $data == chosenFolderId() }">*@
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click:navigate">                      
                        <!-- ko text: $data -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
```

The problem is in this line

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click:navigate">
```

and

```
<li data-bind="css:{active: $data == chosenFolderId() }">
```

Both The line above is not getting attached to the `Navigate` function and `chosenFolderId` observable respectively. It says `Navigate` is undefined . It cannot be parsed`. Same goes for`chosenFolderId`.

Any idea why is it happening ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a few problems with your current approach:

When you use a [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) e.g `data-bind="foreach:Folders"` inside your `ul` the "currect context" will be the items in your folder collection.

So if you want to access the `navigate` or the `chosenFolderId` methods you need to use `$parent`, or `$root` to access the your "root" viewmodel (you can read more about the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)):

```
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix" data-bind="foreach:Folders">
    <li data-bind="css:{active: $data == $parent.chosenFolderId() }">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.navigate">                      
            <!-- ko text: $data -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
    </li>                   
</ul>​
```

You have some problem in your view model as well. If you have complex functions like `navigate` which tries to use `self` you should use a function as a viewmodel instead of an object literal where you can store `this`:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.SelectedFolder = ko.observable('Inbox');
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
    self.navigate = function(folder) {
        self.chosenFolderId(folder);
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());​
```

Note that: your `navigate` function needs a `folder` parameter to make it work and Knockout will pass the current item for you.

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y5cv/).

If you want to do it with an object literal as your view model here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y5cv/1/) which demonstrates that approach.

However you should be aware what are the strength and weeknesses of the two view model creation approach. This SO question summarizes it well: [Difference between knockout View Models declared as object literals vs functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions)

Comment: Yes I already did that with this sought of approach . But I wanted it to do with modular pattern instead of just pushing the bindings through functions . So With your approach perfectly valid . Can't I do the same with My approach ?

Comment: @Joy I don't really following you... you can organize your viewmodel creating function with the modular pattern. Can you maybe update my jsfiddle with the code how you imagine it?

Comment: @Joy There are a few way to make it work with object literals like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y5cv/1/. But you will eventually encounter some cases where it won't be enough for your needs.

Comment: yes the last fiddle which you provided . I actually wanted to put in that way . Well I am pretty novice in knockout as of now . Can you tell why object literals wont alwayz fit for my needs  ? or with a good blog post regarding this ? Sorry If I am too naive in asking this

Comment: @Joy there is a good SO question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions. Also the plurasight courses on KO are quite good altough they are not free.