# Knockout - notify on property change

Tags: javascript, wpf, mvvm, knockout.js, textbox

I try to use Knockout like `WPF-MVVM`.
In `WPF` there is an option to notify the VM on property change.
For example: if I have a textBox, I can use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for notify the VM every click.

```
<Grid DataContext="MyVM">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

In Knockout I have build this simple app:

**VM:**

```
function AppViewModel() {
this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
}, this);


}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

**View:**

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
```

I'm trying ***without success***, to update `fullName` on textBox **input click** (not onblur).

**EDIT:**

The code works fine.
I just want that lastname will update ***while writing*** on the firstname/lastname textbox.

Now it's updated **onblur**, it's not updated while writing.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the current code. I have put it into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/en6AR/ and it works as expected. Perhaps you can explain further the issue you are having.

Comment: The code works fine. I just want that lastname will update while writing on the firstname/lastname textbox.

Now it's updated onblur, it's not updated while writing.

Comment: I see, well that makes more sense. Added an answer describing how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the update mode of an input as you are suggesting there are some built-in ways in knockout to accomplish this.

See this for reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Specifically the part about value updates.

In this case specifically you could use `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` to update the binding.

All that will need to change in this instance is your bindings.

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go caps</button>
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/en6AR/1/

Comment: Thanks! "valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" this what I have been missing

Answer (score 1):

Your code *logically* fine, your problem is in mis-use of `this` inside the `capitalizeLastName` function.

In your case `this` keyword refers to the object the function belongs to, or the `window` object if the function belongs to no object but not your View-Model object. That's why in most KnockoutJS examples we use `var self=this;` at the first line of View-Model definition to obtain a refrence to the View-Model object.

[Updated working demo based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/5WXvF/)

Check the following SO questions for better undertanding:

1. [In knockout.js, why “this” is being assigned to “self”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956898/in-knockout-js-why-this-is-being-assigned-to-self)
2. [this inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963357/this-inside-function)

***Update***

In order to update your view ***while writing*** firstname/lastname textbox, you need just to add `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` to your binding.

From [KnockoutJS documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#parameters):

> valueUpdate
>
> If your binding also includes a parameter called valueUpdate, this
>   defines additional browser events KO should use to detect changes
>   besides the change event. The following string values are the most
>   commonly useful choices:
>
> "afterkeydown" - updates your view model as soon as the user begins
>   typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s keydown event
>   and handling the event asynchronously.

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5WXvF/1/)

Comment: The computed function binds the `this` value in the computed by using the (`function`, `this binding`) method call. So `this` is bound correctly.

Comment: The code works fine. I just want that lastname will update while writing on the firstname/lastname textbox.

Now it's updated onblur, it's not updated while writing.

Comment: Thanks @Gary.S . I updated my answer to be pointed at `capitalizeLastName` function not the `computed` one