# knockout.js: this in child object

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

JS:

```js
function Child() {
    this.method = function() {
         console.dir(this); // this should be 'p.child' <Child> since 
         //'method' called as a property of 'p.child'
         // but when you call it from KO it's actually 'p' <Parent>
    };
}

function Parent() {
    this.child = new Child();
}
var p = new Parent();
ko.applyBindings(p);
```

HTML:

```html
 <a href="#" data-bind="click: child.method">foo</a>
```

Is it bug or a feature I just not understand?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
function Child() {
    var self = this;
    self.method = function() {
         console.dir(self); // this should be 'p.child' <Child> since 
         //'method' called as a property of 'p.child'
         // but when you call it from KO it's actually 'p' <Parent>
    };
}

function Parent() {
    var self = this;
    self.child = new Child();
}
var p = new Parent();
ko.applyBindings(p);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZuHMY/1/

Please see here for the info on `self = this;`

[What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)

**Update**

This also answer's the question about self and this here:

[In knockout.js, why "this" is being assigned to "self"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956898/in-knockout-js-why-this-is-being-assigned-to-self)

Comment: Yes, I know how to solve this problem. I just wondered if it's a bug or there is some logic I misunderstand (some application of LoD e.g.)?

Comment: Why do you make self a global again? wth.

Comment: @EaterOfCode whoops, typo. I forgot to add var self, updated. :)

Comment: "removed var" is there in the commit message, Im a bit confused?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this for sure, but it's possible that knockout is attempting to set the context so that you can operate on the parent from within child functions and subscriptions.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLLF5/1/) shows how you can change the context of a function call using `call(this)`:

```
function Child() {
    this.method = function() {
         console.dir(this);
    };
}

function Parent() {
    this.child = new Child();
} 
var p = new Parent();
p.child.method(); // child
p.child.method.call(p); // parent
```