# KO Array binding not applying?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, knockout.js

Hi I seem to be having a problem with KO array bindings not applying.. Here is my code:

```
var movements_array = [];
var viewModel = { 
    movements: ko.observableArray(movements_array),
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

function get_alteration_movement(){

    for(var i = 0; i < index.movements.length; i++)
    {
        movements_array[i] = index.movements[i].description;
        console.log(movements_array);

        viewModel.movements(movements_array);
        console.log(viewModel.movements);
    }

}
```

Index is JSON data fetched from another js page.

Comment: Your code works well in a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/88jkU/ . Did you get any errors?

Comment: @ArtemVyshniakov impressed by your skills at determining what index should look like :)

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I usually use functions instead of object literals, it's more clear:
[Difference between knockout View Models declared as object literals vs functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions)

```
var viewModel = function(){
    this.movements = ko.observableArray([]);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var model = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
    get_alteration_movement(model);
});

function get_alteration_movement(model) {
    var movements_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < index.movements.length; i++) {
        movements_array[i] = index.movements[i].description;
        console.log(movements_array);
    }

    model.movements(movements_array);
}
```