# How to maintain reference to an instance, when using the setTimeout callback?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How to maintain a reference to an instance, when using the setTimeout callback? E.G:

In my ViewModel (using Knockout)

```
var MyVM = function () {
  this.myFunc = function () {
    setTimeout("this.myCallback()", 2000);
  };
  this.myCallback = function() { this.myObservable(true); }
}
```

This fails.

Comment: why do you need a reference?

Comment: Perhaps OP wants to `clearTimeout`?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte why use `this.myCallback = function() { this.myObservable(true); }` instead of clearTimeout(MyVM);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a private field :

```
var MyVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.myFunc = function () {
        setTimeout(self.myCallback, 2000);
    };
    this.myCallback = function() { self.myObservable(true); }
}
var vm = new MyVM();
```

Have a look at the RP Niemeyer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions).

I hope it helps.