# knockout viewModel ko.computed value not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I’m trying to update a computed knockout value using ko.compute on my current productsList observableArray and my "imageUrl". I keep getting undefined or ImageGalleryId is not a function when I try to get the value.

```
var productModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;

    self.productsList = ko.observableArray([]);

    // I would like to get the image url for the current product
    self.productsList.ImageUrl = ko.computed(function () {

         // returns undefined
         // var imageId = self.productsList.ImageGalleryId;

         // returns: self.productsList.ImageGalleryId is not a function
         // var imageId = self.productsList.ImageGalleryId();

         // Need help **here**
         var imageId = self.productsList.ImageGalleryId();

         var imagePath = "/Image/GetImage/";
         var imageSize = "/175/175/";
         var url = imagePath + imageId + imageSize;
         //console.log(url);
         return url;

    },self); // end ImageUrl

    // Load data when model is created
    self.dummyCompute = ko.computed(function () {
         // start dummyCompute

         //ajax call omitted 
         var JSONdataFromServer = {
           "productsList":[
              {
                 "ProductId":1,
                 "Title":"Product Name",
                 "ImageGalleryId":10,
                                     "ImageUrl":"http://example.com"
              },
                              {
                 "ProductId":2,
                 "Title":"Product Name",
                 "ImageGalleryId":11,
                                     "ImageUrl":"http://example.com"
              }
           ]};

         self.productsList(JSONdataFromServer.productsList);

         }, self); // end dummyCompute

    };

ko.applyBindings(new productModel());
```

Fiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y8yT6/2/

Answer (score 0):

`productsList` is an array, but you're treating it as if it were an object. I assume that you're really trying to deal with the properties of some specific member of the array, but there's nothing in your `computed` that tells it which one is the "current" product.

Once you get that resolved, you want `ProductId` without any parentheses, since it's a plain value and not an `observable`.

Comment: Your statement is true but I cannot find information on how to compute the "current" product. In fact I'm having a hard time finding any information on View Models declared as functions with computed values inside. One thing to notice is that viewModel contains a child list (Is this wrong?) so my Observable does not follow the pattern given on the knockout site below.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html 

Info about literals-vs-functions.
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions