# knockout.js table filter doesn't update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I've been battling with what seems like it should be a really simple Knockout.js task for a number of hours, and after reading multiple websites and questions on SO, I'm still stumped!

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PL8UW/

Essentially I have a table with a "status" column that is bound to a knockout viewmodel.

I also have an observable object that should allow you to filter on various statuses

If i bind the table directly to the data object everything shows, but if I bind to the computed, then nothing shows.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="foo" type="checkbox" checked /> Foo
    <input id="bar" type="checkbox" checked /> Bar
</form>
<div id="tableDiv">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredData">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="html: id"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="html: status"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

javascript:
    var data = [
        {"id": 1, "status": "foo"},
        {"id": 2, "status": "bar"}, 
        {"id": 3, "status": "foo"},
        {"id": 4, "status": "foo"},
        {"id": 5, "status": "bar"}];

```
var viewModel = { 
    tableData: ko.observableArray(data),
    filter: ko.observable({'foo': ko.observable(true), 'bar': ko.observable(true)}),
    filteredData: ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.tableData, function(item) {
            return viewModel.filter[item.Status];
        });
    })    
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('tableDiv'));

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    viewModel.filter[this.id] = this.checked;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous smaller, bigger errors in your fiddle which are coming from two fundamental problem (beside the fact that your design your storing the filter and little bit complicated and you are mixing the jQuery event handlers with Kncokout viewmodels):

- `ko.observable` is returning a function so to get its value you need to write `someObservable()` and to set its value you need to write  `someObservable(newValue)` ([documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html))
- you need to use the `deferEvaluation: true` option if you are using `ko.computed` declared on object literals in order to access the object itself inside the computed. (see also: [Difference between knockout View Models declared as object literals vs functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions))

So here is a fixed version of your code with comments:

```
var viewModel = { 
    tableData: ko.observableArray(data),
    filter: ko.observable({'foo': ko.observable(true), 'bar': ko.observable(true)}),
    filteredData: ko.computed(function() {
        // missing () after viewModel.tableData
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.tableData(), function(item) {
            //missing () after filter and at the end
            //typo: Satus should be status
            return viewModel.filter()[item.status]();
        });
        //deferEvaluation was needed to refernce viewModel inside the computed
    }, null, {deferEvaluation: true}) 
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('tableDiv'));

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    //missing () after filter missing () to set the observable value
    viewModel.filter()[this.id](this.checked);
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fFvF/).

Here is a different solution using the [`checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) for handling the filter:

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UV35M/).

Comment: Thanks - this is my first time using knockout.js and your answer uses bits that I've never even seen before! Time for me to do more reading I think! :)