# How to get a ko.computed to work on observables inside an object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a fairly simple view model to hold an array of data and take a string which I want to use to filter the data.

I have some very simple mark-up to render it like this:

```
<section class="task-list">
    <ul data-bind="foreach:filteredRecords">
        <li>
            <label>Task name:</label>
            <span data-bind="text:TaskName"></span>              
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

and I've set up the model as follows;

```
var viewModel = {

    searchText : ko.observable(''),
    taskData : ko.observableArray([]),

    searchData : function () {

        // use ko.utils.arrayFilter to limit records by searchText()
        return this.taskData();
    },

    filterRecords: ko.computed(this.searchData, this).extend({ throttle: 500 }),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('.task-list')[0]);
```

What I get is

```
Uncaught Error: Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed
```

moving the function back inside the ko:computed like this:

```
 filteredRecords: ko.computed(function () {
        return this.taskData();
    },this).extend({ throttle: 500 })
```

just gives me this error insread:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'taskData'
```

So tried to define another property to use instead:

```
var viewModel = {

    _self : this,

    searchText : ko.observable(''),
    taskData : ko.observableArray([]),

    filteredRecords: ko.computed(function () {
        return this.taskData();
    },this).extend({ throttle: 500 })
};
```

but this now gives the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _self is not defined
```

finally I tried doing this:

```
var viewModel = {

    searchText : ko.observable(''),
    taskData : ko.observableArray([]),

    filteredRecords: ko.computed(function() {
        var me = this;
        return function () {
            return me.taskData();
        }
    },this).extend({ throttle: 500 })
};
```

Now this, does not throw any of the previous errors but also does not yield any results in the HTML either...

[I've set up a Fiddle at](http://jsfiddle.net/7re34/)

How do I correctly apply a ko.computed to an object so that I can use the observable and observableArray that I have inside the object?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you are defining an object literal, you are not able to reference any of the properties of it until after it is created.  The value of `this` will not be your new object.

You can either use a constructor function like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.searchText = ko.observableArray();
   this.taskData = ko.observableArray([]);

   this.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function() {
        //filter logic here, can use `this` and reference searchText/taskData
    },this).extend({ throttle: 500 })
};
```

then, create a new instance of it like:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), $('.task-list')[0]);
```

Otherwise, you could create your `viewModel` first before adding the computed.  Then do:

```
viewModel.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function() {
  //filter logic here, can use `this` and reference searchText/taskData
}, viewModel);
```

This answer might help too: [Difference between knockout View Models declared as object literals vs functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions/9590133#9590133)

Comment: ko.computed() triggered only one time .After that its not at all triggering...How to use with object literal?