# Checkbox onclick in knockout is not updating viewmodel

Tags: javascript, java, knockout.js

I have list of check boxes, on click of any checkbox i need to get all checked check boxes. To do that I am calling the java script function "ChangeColumnSelection".

The issue is, the clicked check box is not updating view model immediately. When i click next text box, I am seeing that the previously check box value got updated in the view model.

```
 <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: SelectionColumnList">
      <li class="list-group-item">
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {onclick: 'javascript:ChangeColumnSelection(\'' + ColumnID + '\')'}, checked: IsSelected"
                        class="pull-xs-left push-down rightmargin" />
          <span data-bind="text: ColumnName"></span>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

**Update:**

My view model is

```
  var dynamicGridViewModel = {
        SelectionColumnList: ko.observableArray([])
   }; 

    selectionInfo.ColumnID = columnInfo.ColumnID;
    selectionInfo.ColumnName = columnInfo.ColumnName;
    selectionInfo.DisplayOrder = columnInfo.DisplayOrder;
    selectionInfo.SortType = 'None';
    selectionInfo.IsSelected = true;
    dynamicGridViewModel.SelectionColumnList.push(selectionInfo);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `onclick` events. You can achieve this just with [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

```js
var array = [{
  ColumnID: 1,
  ColumnName: "ColumnName 1"
}, {
  ColumnID: 2,
  ColumnName: "ColumnName 2"
}]

var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.SelectionColumnList = ko.observableArray(array);
  
  // no need to populate the array manually. Knockout will take care of it
  self.chosenItems = ko.observableArray();

  // every time chosenItems array changes, subscribe callback function gets triggered
  self.chosenItems.subscribe(function() {
    console.log(self.chosenItems());
  })
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: SelectionColumnList">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: ColumnID, checked: $parent.chosenItems" />
    <span data-bind="text: ColumnName"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here, `ColumnId` is set as the value of `checkbox` input. Hence, the `chosenItems` array will be an array of selected `ColumnId`s.

The great thing about Knockout is that, it allows not only [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) like string, number or bool for `checkedValue`, but objects too. If you want the entire `Column` object to be populated in `chosenItems`, then you can set the `checkedValue` like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.chosenItems" />
```

If you want to perform some operation upon changing of any checkbox's state, you can perform that inside the [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) callback. This function gets triggered every time the array changes.

(Also, the proper way to add a [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) is `data-bind="click: clickFunction"`)

**UPDATE:**

You're using an object literal as your viewModel. I suggest you create viewModel function and use the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator. If you want to bind `checked` to a boolean property of `Column`, then you can create a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property and `subscribe` to that computed property:

```js
var columns = [{
  ColumnID: 1,
  ColumnName: "ColumnName 1",
  IsSelected: false
}, {
  ColumnID: 2,
  ColumnName: "ColumnName 2",
  IsSelected: true
}];

var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.SelectionColumnList = ko.observableArray([]);

  // this property has the selected ColumnIds
  self.selectedItems = ko.computed(() => {
    // If you're using ES6 systax
    // return self.SelectionColumnList()
    //  .filter(column => column.IsSelected())
    //   .map(column => column.ColumnID);

    // out of the columns, get the ColumnIds with IsSelected as true
    return self.SelectionColumnList()
      .filter(function(column) {
        return column.IsSelected();
      })
      .map(function(column) {
        return column.ColumnID
      });
  });

  // gets triggered everytime checkbox is checked/unchecked
  self.selectedItems.subscribe(function() {
    console.log(self.selectedItems());
  });
}

// create a new instance of the viewmodel
var dynamicGridViewModel = new viewModel();

// loop through the columns and populate the observableArray
columns.forEach(function(columnInfo) {
  var selectionInfo = {};

  selectionInfo.ColumnID = columnInfo.ColumnID;
  selectionInfo.ColumnName = columnInfo.ColumnName;

  // this property must be an observable
  selectionInfo.IsSelected = ko.observable(columnInfo.IsSelected);

  dynamicGridViewModel.SelectionColumnList.push(selectionInfo);
})

ko.applyBindings(dynamicGridViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: SelectionColumnList">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected" />
    <span data-bind="text: ColumnName"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Here's a fiddle for testing**](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/9ejtj6sn/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added click binding as you suggested, but click event not only fires on click, it also when populating data to view model.

Comment: @sivaprakash I added the `click` binding documentation just as an additional resource. You don't need it in your case. Did you completely ignore what I wrote above the click binding part :D You need to change your `checked` binding. Read the answer on how to implement checked binding properly. Go through the documentation links I added. Click on the `Run code snippet` to see the working example

Comment: Thanks, click problem is solved.
I wanted checkedValue to be bind with boolean property and Checked should push entire object to selectedItems view model

Comment: @sivaprakash I'm assuming each `Column` has a `IsSelected` property? Please add all relevant parts of your viewmodel to the question.

Comment: I have included my view model

Comment: @sivaprakash I have updated the answer. Please check it and let me know

Comment: I changed my view model to function view model, but I'm not able to ass items to observable array outsider view model.

Comment: dynamicGridViewModel.FilterColumnList.push(filterInfo);

Comment: @sivaprakash As you can see in the answer, you have to create an object by using the `new` operator:  `var dynamicGridViewModel = new viewModel();`

Comment: @sivaprakash If your function itself is called `dynamicGridViewModel`, then call the instance something else like:  `var gridInstance = new dynamicGridViewModel()`. Then bind `gridInstance.FilterColumnList.push(filterInfo)`

Comment: I need to push an item to array property of existing view model.
I don't want to create new view model

Comment: Are you not allowed to change from an `object literal` to a `function()` ?

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21554907/3082296) on how to add a `computed` property to an object literal.

Comment: I have changed my view model to functional view model

var dynamicGridViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
    self.FilterColumnList = ko.observableArray([])
};

Comment: var filterInfo = {};
                        filterInfo.ColumnID = columnInfo.ColumnID;
dynamicGridViewModel.FilterColumnList.push(filterInfo);

Im not able to add like above

Comment: `dynamicGridViewModel ` is a function.You can't access `FilterColumnList` like `dynamicGridViewModel.FilterColumnList`. You need to create an object using the `new` operator. This is similar to how a `class` works in C# or java. You can't access the property by `classname.property`. You need to create an instance of the class first. [So in javascript, it is done by using the `new` keyword against a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859846/3082296). Like this: `var gridInstance = new dynamicGridViewModel()`. Then use `gridInstance.FilterColumnList ` etc