# What am I doing wrong here with knockout computed?

Tags: knockout.js

This [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Pxf/4/) is working fine, but when I change it to this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Pxf/7/) nothing:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.limitCharacters = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
    {
        var allowedNumberOfCharacters = valueAccessor();
        var currentValue = allBindingsAccessor.get('value');
        var cutText = ko.unwrap(currentValue).substr(0, allowedNumberOfCharacters);
        currentValue(cutText);
    }
};

var viewModel = {
    comment : ko.observable(""),
    count : ko.computed(function(){
        var countNum = 20 - viewModel.comment().length;
        return countNum;
    })
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[DEMO not working](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Pxf/7/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are insist to use [an object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions) as your view model you need set the [`deferEvaluation` to `true` on your computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#constructing-a-computed-observable) in order to access the `viewModel` inside the computed:

```
var viewModel = {
    comment : ko.observable(""),
    count : ko.computed(function(){
        var countNum = 20 - viewModel.comment().length;
        return countNum;
    }, null,  { deferEvaluation: true })
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WmLb/).

Or declare your computed after you have created the `viewModel` object:

```
var viewModel = {
    comment: ko.observable(""),
};
viewModel.count = ko.computed(function () {
    var countNum = 20 - viewModel.comment().length;
    return countNum;
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AKTgg/).

Comment: somehow it doesn't work in durandal it is the same but with `return viewModel`  point a breackpoint gives me `<return>: undefined`

Comment: Then this is something which is durandal related, so you should post this issue as a separate question including your durandal viewModel.

Comment: can you please check this now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741620/what-am-i-doing-wrong-here-returing-viewmodel