# toJSON Parsing return empty text my Knockoutjs function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have problem in parsing my model to JSON:

```
    var UserViewModel = function (UserName, Password) {
        this.UserName = ko.observable(UserName);
        this.Password = ko.observable(Password);


    this.loginClick = function () {

        var strJSON = ko.toJSON(this);
```

alert(strJSON);
        };
    };

```
    ko.applyBindings(UserViewModel);
```

Alert gives empty dialog box,

if i pass arguments to `ko.toJSON`

```
var strJSON = ko.toJSON({
    'UserName': this.UserName,
    'Password': this.Password
});
alert(strJSON);
```

then it is giving right json string.

Comment: Also highly related: [Difference between knockout View Models declared as object literals vs functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions?rq=1)

Comment: If you have some other specif problem with your JSON parsing then edit your question with the concrete problem, error messages, etc. and I will vote to reopen your question.

Comment: The question is still rather unclear to me tbh. The last edit only changed the title. You speak of "self" which is not in your code, and of a "problem" but you don't state what the problem is. Please be specific about your issue and make sure the code in the question helps us repro the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/yJqmQE9WXVLODTrYbtQ0?p=preview

The 
**this**
 in the loginClick function doesn't point to UserViewModel.

And your ko.applyBindings is incorrect.