# ko.dependentObservable inside viewModel?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I m new to Knowckout.js and have done this demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yawer/7QXCN/#&togetherjs=Aunph9nuxf

In this implementation dependentobervable is out side viewModel. My question is, is there a way fullname which is a dependentObservable can come inside viewModel just like name and other properties ?

Below is my code:

```
$(function(){

var viewModel={
    name: ko.observable("Biala"),
    changedName: function(){
    this.name("Hussain");
},
    nvtoggle: ko.observable(true)

};

viewModel.fullName= ko.dependentObservable(function(){
    return this.name() + " is " + (this.nvtoggle() ? " " : " not ") + "visible";
},viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

});

Comment: Not really, if you are using object literals as your view model... but why is it a problem if the fullName is "outside"? See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions

Comment: @nemesv its not a problem, as I m new to knockout, this stuck in mind, why it need to have out side of class, as it is sort of calculated property, why not it is inside class ?

Comment: Also note that `dependant observables` are now `computed observables` http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/dependentObservables.html

Comment: @haansi in this case the linked question should also answer yours? Or is something still not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible to put the dependantObservable into the viewmodel :)

Please see the code below and attached jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/B6AtE/1/.

A few things to note:

- I have changed your dependantObservable to a `computed`, as this is what they are now called.
- I have changed your viewmodel to be a `function` and have moved it outside of your ready function. This is just to be tidy - it works fine if you leave it all in the ready function.
- I have added `var self = this;` at the beginning of the viewmodel. This has no functional effect in this case, but is a good idea to do this in your viewmodels. After adding it in, you can use `self` within that viewmodel and be certain that you are in the right context.

Please let me know if you have any other questions about the changes that I have made.

> var viewModel = function() {
>
> ```
> var self = this;
> self.name = ko.observable("Biala");
> self.changedName = function() {
>     self.name("Hussain");
> };
> self.nvtoggle = ko.observable(true);
>
> self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
>     return self.name() + " is " + (self.nvtoggle() ? " " : " not ") + "visible";
> });
> ```
>
> };
>
> $(function(){
>
> ```
> var vm = new viewModel();                                
> ko.applyBindings(vm);
> ```
>
> });

Comment: thanks, well written code with really nice explanation. Just a small thing please. var self=this; is representing this keyword right ? It means instead of self I can use this in all places right ?

Comment: Almost - it's the other way around. The problem with just using `this` is that it refers to the current scope. For example, if you called `this.name = ko.observable("Biala");`, the `this` in this case refers to the viewmodel. But if you call `return this.name()` inside the computed, `this` refers to **the computed**. If you write `var self = this;` at the beginning, you can always use `self` and be certain that you are referring to the viewmodel.

There is a good explaination on the Knockout site, under "Managing This" - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html