# How to display a property in JavaScript object using Knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I am new to Knockoutjs and JavaScript, and need some advice.

In my HTML (View) page, I am trying to show a text property from my Javascript object (Model), which looks something like:

```
var object = function() {
   this.text = "blah blah blah";
}
```

In my Object's ViewModel, I have this:

```
var objectViewModel= function (object) {
   var content = ko.observable(object); // or is it object.text() ?

   self.section = function() {
      return content.text; //or is it content ?
   }
}
```

And in my view, I have this:

```
<span data-bind="text:section"></span>
```

My main question is how do I make the HTML show a model's property (the text) via viewmodel? I commented in my other questions, and would like some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'd recommend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions/9590133#9590133) as a good read.

To answer both of the additional commented questions: *It all depends on what you passed as the parameter*. That important bit of information would be provided when you instantiate your viewmodel, which you left out.

As specified, you'll need to `ko.applyBindings(new objectViewModel(new object()))`.
Secondly, you have `self`, where did it come from? Make it `this` or declare `var self = this;` or provide the rest of the code from which that variable is coming from.

Next, from within the `section` function you need to "read" your content observable:

```
return content().text
```

Finally, in your view you need to execute `section`:

```
<span data-bind="text:section()"></span>
```

---

As an additional consideration, you could make `section` a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) with a dependency on `content`.

```
this.section = ko.computed(function() {
  return content().text;
})
```

which removes the need to execute in the view. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/kmJ75/) with two different scenarios depicted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Sorry I didn't reference what 'self' was (it's 'this')