# Computed function not being invoked

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following view-model

```
var viewModel = {
FLFSExamIsH: ko.observable(true),
FLFSROIEntryFieldDynPosBottom: ko.computed(function() {
    return this.FLFSExamIsH ? "flfs_ROIImagesRow3Pos" : "flfs_ROIImagesRow2Pos";
}),
```

};

in my html page I am binding a div as follows:

```
data-bind='css: FLFSROIEntryFieldDynPosBottom'
```

at some point in my code, I execute: viewModel.FLFSExamIsH(false);

But at all times (in the chrome debugger) viewModel.FLFSROIEntryFieldDynPosBottom() is always returning the 'flfs_ROIImagesRow2Pos', regardless of the update to the viewmodel: viewModel.FLFSExamIsH()

Setting a breakpoint on the computed function and updating that model variable doesn't re-evaluate the computed function either.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing parenthesis at

```
return this.FLFSExamIsH ? "flfs_ROIImagesRow3Pos" : "flfs_ROIImagesRow2Pos";
//                    ^^^ here, it should be this.FLFSExamIsH()
```

Plus since you are using not using a function to define your viewmodel, the computed should be added after (check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions) for more info):

```
var viewModel = {
    FLFSExamIsH: ko.observable(true),
};
viewModel.FLFSROIEntryFieldDynPosBottom = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.FLFSExamIsH() 
                 ? "flfs_ROIImagesRow3Pos" 
                 : "flfs_ROIImagesRow2Pos";
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/stEhA/)**

Comment: this change causes an exception: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'

Comment: There was another problem, answer updated with example

Comment: See my answer about that

Comment: @Anders yes indeed, I always keep [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions) in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `this` keyword if you do not use a function constructor.