# How to create objects as literals rather than functions in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In his book "*Javascript - the good parts*", Douglas Crockford mentions this about the Constructor Invocation Pattern (which is the way we would instantiate a simili-class with the use of the `new` keyword:

> The Constructor Invocation Pattern JavaScript is a prototypal
>   inheritance language. That means that objects can inherit properties
>   directly from other objects. The language is class-free. This is a
>   radical departure from the current fashion. Most languages today are
>   classi- cal. Prototypal inheritance is powerfully expressive, but is
>   not widely understood. JavaScript itself is not confident in its
>   prototypal nature, so it offers an object-making syntax that is
>   reminiscent of the classical languages. Few classical programmers
>   found prototypal inheritance to be acceptable, and classically
>   inspired syntax obscures the language’s true prototypal nature. It is
>   the worst of both worlds. If a function is invoked with the new
>   prefix, then a new object will be created with a hidden link to the
>   value of the function’s prototype member, and this will be bound to
>   that new object. The new prefix also changes the behavior of the
>   return statement.

```
 // Create a constructor function called Quo.
 // It makes an object with a status property.
 var Quo = function (string) {
     this.status = string;
 };
 // Give all instances of Quo a public method

 // called get_status.
 Quo.prototype.get_status = function () { 
     return this.status;
 };
 // Make an instance of Quo.
 var myQuo = new Quo("confused");
 document.writeln(myQuo.get_status()); // confused
```

> Functions that are intended to be used with the new prefix are called constructors. By convention, they are kept in variables with a
>   capitalized name. If a constructor is called without the new prefix,
>   very bad things can happen without a compile-time or runtime warning,
>   so the capitalization convention is really important. Use of this
>   style of constructor functions is not recommended...
>
> ...If the function was invoked with the new prefix and the return value is not an object, then this (the new object) is returned
>   instead.

He then suggests to rather use the closure to avoid the constructor invocation, like so:

```
// Create a maker function called quo. It makes an
// object with a get_status method and a private
// status property.

var quo = function (status) {
    return {
        get_status: function () { return status;} 
    };
};
// Make an instance of quo.
var myQuo = quo("amazed");
document.writeln(myQuo.get_status( ));
```

My question is this one: Is there a way NOT to use the constructor invocation with the applyBinding() call in knockout and build objects as literals instead of as functions? And use `object.create()` instead of `new` keyword?

Comment: When you say use object literals in applyBindings do you mean for example-> var myViewModel{personName:'Bob'};ko.applyBinding(myViewModel); Because this can be done in KO.

Comment: Highly related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions?rq=1

Comment: If you've read through the other question you could see numerious examples of using object literals with Kncokout both in the question and in the answers also the kncokout homepage is full of them. So you can of course use KO with object literals you just have to do some extra when it comes to computed, click handlers etc. which is explained again in the linked question.