# lodash/fp _.extend doesn't mutate the first parameter as it does in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

[According to the lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#assignIn), `_.extend(object, [sources])` mutates the first parameter.

```js
var dest = {
  a: 1
};
_.extend(dest, {
  b: 2
});

// expect { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
// actual { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
console.log(dest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

When using lodash/fp, this is not the case *([argument order is unchanged](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#exceptions-to-the-rules))*:

```js
var dest = {
  a: 1
};
_.extend(dest, {
  b: 2
});

// expect { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
// actual { "a": 1 }
console.log(dest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.fp.js"></script>
```

This is problematic as I have a lot of code that mutates `this`. Is this a bug in lodash and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to configure lodash/fp to allow mutations.

```js
var fp = _.convert({
  'immutable': false
})
var dest = {
  a: 1
};
fp.extend(dest, {
  b: 2
});

// expect { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
// actual { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
console.log(dest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.fp.js"></script>
```

I am using KnockoutJS with viewModels defined as functions, which necessitates mutating `this`. If I don't want to disable immutability with lodash/fp, I can define my viewModels as object literals instead. [More here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug: immutability is a functional programming trait and it's stated at the very beginning of the guide:

> The lodash/fp module promotes a more functional programming (FP)
>   friendly style by exporting an instance of lodash with its methods
>   wrapped to produce immutable auto-curried iteratee-first data-last
>   methods.

I think you should reconsider using lodash/fp or mutations, they don't play well together.

---

**Edit:** well I was mistaken, they *can* play together: see [Musical Store's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068590/1633783)

Comment: I understand that now, but in my case I need to mutate `this`. `this` can only be mutated, it cannot be assigned to.