# knockout tutorials - "this" property binding?

Tags: function, knockout.js, properties, this, bind

These are from the knockoutjs.com tutorials.

Can anyone explain what the "this" at the end of the fullName property does? Please mention the JS principle at work here so that I may read about further, thanks!

[image]

Why does the totalSurcharge property not need the "this" at the end?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to a `ko.computed` sets the value of `this` when the function to determine the computed's value (the first arg) is executed. In the `fullName` case, the function uses `this.firstName` and `this.lastName`. So, whenever it is called we want to make sure that `this` is indeed our viewmodel.

In the second case, a variable called `self` was created that points to the appropriate value of `this`. Then, `self` is used inside the computed's function rather than using `this` (which is dynamic). In the second case, `self` could have been put as the second argument and then `this` could have been used inside the function.

This is really a matter of style. In my opinion, the use of a variable like `self` has fallen out of style these days. In the end, it comes down to personal preference.

Here is another answer that discusses `this` in KO as well: [Difference between knockout View Models declared as object literals vs functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions/9590133#9590133)

Good tutorial on `this` in JavaScript here: https://derickbailey.com/email-courses/masteringthis/

Comment: Theres also a small explanation in the KO docs page: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html