# Where should I use parentheses with Knockout Computed and arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I am combining an Options binding and a Computed, and am getting the error in the Firebug console:

TypeError: this.selectedCountryNeverNull is undefined

This is the relevant part of the ViewModel:

```
    // Constructor for an object with two properties
    var Country = function (name, population) {
        this.countryName = name;
        this.countryPopulation = population;
    };

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries: ko.observableArray([
            new Country("UK", 65000000),
            new Country("USA", 320000000),
            new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
        ]),
        selectedCountry: ko.observable(), // Nothing selected by default
        selectedCountryNeverNull: ko.observable(), // has default
        selectedCountryDesc: ko.computed(function () { return '*' + this.selectedCountryNeverNull.countryName + '*'; }, this)
    };
```

and this is the select:

```
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountryNeverNull"></select>
```

I left out the `optionsCaption:` so that the first array element is the default, and the value is never null.

Firebug says the error is in the `ko.computed` line, and I tried to add `()` parentheses here and there, but with no avail.

I want to do much bigger `ko.computed` stuff, but isolated my problem in this extension of an example from the knockout site.

Thanks for any help in trying to understand the parentheses issues in general and mine particular.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a combination of `this` context which can wrap you in circles when using knockout, and parantheses.. In your viewmodel do a `var self = this;` line to start and use `self` in place of `this`. Also an observable, observablearray, and computed are all functions, so toss in the parantheses when referencing them `return '*' + this.selectedCountryNeverNull().countryName + '*';`

Comment: @JNevill You mean I should convert from `var viewModel` to `function viewModel` ?

Comment: No. I mean creating a variable for `this` to be referenced down in your computed. Take a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419/difference-between-knockout-view-models-declared-as-object-literals-vs-functions)

Comment: [And the documentation for knockout here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) describing the convention of using `var self = this` to avoid mistakenly pointing to the wrong thing.

Comment: @JNevill Good pointers, I will definitely study those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three problems with your code:

1. `this` in your `ko.computed` refers to `Window`, not to `viewModel`,
2. The `select` binding sets its value at the time of `applyBindings`, so for a brief period of time, `selectedCountryNeverNull` is actually undefined. This means you'll have to set it with a default manually or check for falsey values in your comptued
3. In the computed, you'll need to use the `()` to get `selectedCountryNeverNull`'s value and create a dependency.

An example on how to fix all three:

1. Use a constructor and the `new` keyword to manage `this`,
2. Default to an empty object in the computed ( `|| {}` )
3. Call the observable in the computed ( `()` )

```js
// Constructor for an object with two properties
var Country = function(name, population) {
  this.countryName = name;
  this.countryPopulation = population;
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.availableCountries = ko.observableArray([
    new Country("UK", 65000000),
    new Country("USA", 320000000),
    new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
  ]);
  
  this.selectedCountry = ko.observable(); // Nothing selected by default
  
  this.selectedCountryNeverNull = ko.observable(); // has default
  
  this.selectedCountryDesc = ko.computed(function() {
    return '*' + (this.selectedCountryNeverNull() || {}).countryName + '*';
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountryNeverNull"></select>
                   
Selection: <span data-bind="text: selectedCountryDesc"></span>
```

Comment: I got your answer to work after converting `var viewModel = function` to `function ViewModel() {...`

Comment: That's essentially the same thing but the order of your code matters. Have a look at this explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn

Comment: Also my "trick" of not using the "optionsCaption:" does not eliminate the danger of the selectedCountry being null ? Is that not possible? My mother taught me: always initialize your variables, but here that seems not so easy

Comment: I tried to explain this in point 2... When you define your `computed`, it runs once to find out its initial value. At this time, `selectedCountryNeverNull` is `undefined`, so it won't have a `countryName` property and throw an error. Once you call `applyBindings`, the binding sets the value. But this is too late for it to recover...

Comment: I see. And ` || {}` is the rescue, then `{}` is defined, but isn't this "nothing" or empty? Seems like I need to read more of my 1000 page JS book

Comment: When you have an object (`{}`) and try to retreive a property that doesn't exist, javascript returns `undefined`. So: `{}.countryName` => `undefined`. When you have `null` or `undefined`, and you try to retreive a property, javascript throws an error. So: `undefined.countryName` => `Error: Cannot read property 'countryName' of undefined`

Comment: Great, thanks. Basically, I was trying to avoid verbose stuff like `selectedCountry() ? selectedCountry().countryName : 'unknown'`, but your shorthand notation is a better solution than omitting `optionsCaption:`