# issue with filter binding with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new working with Knockout.js framework and I'm having the following error in my code, I'm building an application using Knockout.js, everything works fine except when I tried to create a dependentObservable.

This is the javascript code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    console.log("This is my Application");

     var app = {
         mapElement: document.getElementById('map'),
         mapObj: map,
         locations : ko.observableArray([
            {id: 1, title: 'Holywood Theater', location: {lat: 43.098344, lng: -76.145697}},
            {id: 2, title: 'Mattydale Fire Department', location: {lat: 43.098172, lng: -76.142189}},
            {id: 3, title: 'Original Italian Pizza', location: {lat: 43.098854, lng:  -76.144700}},
            {id: 4, title: 'Roxboro Road Middle School', location: {lat: 43.101110, lng: -76.150901}},
            {id: 5, title: 'Big Lots', location: {lat: 43.101400, lng: -76.146985}},
            {id: 6, title: 'Camnel pub', location: {lat: 43.098670, lng: -76.145832}}
        ]),
        markers:[],
        textFilter: ko.observable(),
        filterLocations: ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(app.locations(), function (loc) {
                                return loc.title().toLowerCase().includes(app.textFilter().toLowerCase());
                            });
                        })
     };

    ko.applyBindings(app);
})();
```

The error in the chrome console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locations' of undefined

Comment: Can you provide the html as well or a jsfiddle?

Comment: it seems that you can't use 'app' var because you're still creating it.

Comment: @EdilsonBorges it's actually the correct answer. Post it below.

Comment: This solves your problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590133/4065876.

Comment: Thanks, @f_martinez. I've posted

Comment: Thanks you are all right. thanks for your help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using object literal for viewmodels, you should define your computed/dependent observables as

```
app.filterLocations = ko.computed(function () {
                        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.locations(), function (loc) {
                            return loc.title.toLowerCase().includes(app.textFilter().toLowerCase());
                        });
                    }, app);
```

Notice passing of `app` object as second parameter to computed function that defines scope for `this`.

Also use `computed` instead of `dependentObservable`.

[Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Comment: thanks so much for your help, definitely you are correct, thanks for your help on this

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 'app' var because you're still creating it.

```
var app = {... 

    ^^^    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(app.locations(), ...

                                       ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks @Edilson Borges