# Knockout js - why does binding work without any reference to the viewModel

Tags: knockout.js

Playing around with knockout.js, I still don't really get the underlying logic. In the following example, the static javascript array `boxList` does not have any reference to or by the viewModel, which is in fact totally empty. Still, the foreach binding has no difficulties to grasp the array. Why?

---

note: obviously, the binding only works when `ko.applyBindings` has been called, with an empty viewModel as argument.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach : boxList">
            <div><input type="checkbox" ><label data-bind="text: name"></label></div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
 var viewModel = {

    };

  var boxList = [
            { name : 'n1'},
            { name : 'n2' },
            { name : 'n3'},
            { name : 'n4' },
        ];


   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e85sLmk4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `foreach: boxList` the binding expression is a valid Javascript expression, i.e. access to the global variable `boxList`. Hence Knockout is able to resolve the variable and render the checkboxes for it.

```js
var viewModel = {

 };

 var boxList = [{
   name: 'n1'
 }, {
   name: 'n2'
 }, {
   name: 'n3'
 }, {
   name: 'n4'
 }, ];


 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach : boxList">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you had used that binding inside a `foreach` binding, or with `$root` or `$data` contexts, it would be necessary to have those variables under the view model. So a binding expression like `foreach : $root.boxList` will not work if variable `boxList` is not declared in the view model.

```js
var viewModel = {

 };

 var boxList = [{
   name: 'n1'
 }, {
   name: 'n2'
 }, {
   name: 'n3'
 }, {
   name: 'n4'
 }, ];


 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach : $root.boxList">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I stll don't get what the content of the viewModel object is for. I built an entire app without any properties in the viewModel.

Comment: It is not something special. VM is supposed to be a valid JS object. Some people create it as just an object, some use a constructor to create the object dynamically. Essentially declaring variables and methods inside a view model helps avoid cluttering global namespace. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590133/5894241