# Knockout.js: How to update property on the basis of another observable array

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How i can change value of one column on the basis of another column value change.In the following code i want to update % column using marks columns value change.

**HTML:**

```
<table data-bind="foreach: users()">
  <thead class="flip-content table-head">
    <tr>

      <th align="center">Name</th>
      <th align="center">Marks</th>
      <th align="center">% out of 100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr >
    <td data-bind="text: $data.name()"> </td>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="value: $data.marks()" />
    </td>
    <td data-bind='text:  $data.percent()'></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
var UserModel = function () {
  this.users = ko.observableArray([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: ko.observable('Bob'),
      marks: ko.observable(0),
      percent: ko.computed(function () {
        //percentage formula
      }, this)
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: ko.observable('Jane'),
      marks: ko.observable(0),
      percent: ko.computed(function () {
        //percentage formula
      }, this)
    }
  ]);
  this.selectedUser = ko.observable(this.users()[0]);
}
var userModel = new UserModel();
ko.applyBindings(userModel);
```

How i can do this.

Comment: You won't be able to write a computedObservable that way. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590133/4887159

Comment: you should use `data-bind="value: $data.marks"` `exclude ()` which is used to read a observable (2 way binding is lost).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most common solution is to use "class" instances rather than plain objects. These allow you to easily select the right `marks` value because inside the constructor, `this` refers to the current user.

```js
var User = function(id, name, marks) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.marks = ko.observable(marks);
  this.percent = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.marks() + "%";
  }, this);
}

var UserModel = function () {
  this.users = ko.observableArray([
    new User(1, "Bob", 10),
    new User(2, "Alice", 30), 
  ]);
  this.selectedUser = ko.observable(this.users()[0]);
}
var userModel = new UserModel();
ko.applyBindings(userModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table data-bind="foreach: users()">
  <thead class="flip-content table-head">
    <tr>

      <th align="center">Name</th>
      <th align="center">Marks</th>
      <th align="center">% out of 100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr >
    <td data-bind="text: name"> </td>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="value: marks" />
    </td>
    <td data-bind='text: percent'></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

If you absolutely need to use plain objects, you can define `percent`'s logic on your parent model and pass a reference to the current item in the view to create a computed on the fly. (I wouldn't recommend this)

```js
var UserModel = function () {
  this.users = ko.observableArray([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: ko.observable('Bob'),
      marks: ko.observable(0)
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: ko.observable('Jane'),
      marks: ko.observable(0)
    }
  ]);
  
  this.selectedUser = ko.observable(this.users()[0])
};

UserModel.prototype.percentageFor = function(user) {
  return user.marks() + "%";
};

var userModel = new UserModel();
ko.applyBindings(userModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table data-bind="foreach: users()">
  <thead class="flip-content table-head">
    <tr>

      <th align="center">Name</th>
      <th align="center">Marks</th>
      <th align="center">% out of 100</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr >
    <td data-bind="text: name"> </td>
    <td>
      <input data-bind="value: marks" />
    </td>
    <td data-bind='text: $parent.percentageFor($data)'></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```