# Using carousel and an updated Knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, foreach, carousel

I have this small project I'm working at, and it's my first time ever using KnockoutJS (and a long while since I used javascript).

Any javascript carousel works with `foreach`, *until* the array is updated. I have already tried using Glider, Slick and Owl plugins and they all end up doing the same thing:

1. Document starts, foreach initiates, populates the carousel with cards fetched from URL. OK
2. Using the `<select>`, I change the option which will return a different API URL based on it. OK
3. The foreach is restarted, the new content is thrown in the data-bind, but **the last carousel remains in HTML, working** (?)
4. The new content doesn't work well with the carousel, as the items show stacked on top of each other.

The fourth step actually happened long before I understood what happened with carousels and lifecycle from KO; I had to use a `handleBinding` to start the plugin function **after** the foreach was made. Problem is, when the foreach is updated, KO won't restart the whole view, just what's inside of it, so the handleBinding is ignored.

Also, I can't explain why, in the 3rd step, the last carousel keeps there.

Code:

Select

```
<div id="select-regiao" data-bind="with: localizacoes" class="form-group mb-0">
            <select id="selected-option" data-bind="options: planosPorLocalizacao, value: planosSelecionados" class="custom-select select-oi mr-2">
          </select>
        </div>
```

Carousel, foreach, card...

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-bind="foreach: planos, carousel">
        <!-- #region card do plano -->
        <div class="mt-4 m-2">
          <div class="card card-plano">
          [... card content... ]
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #endregion -->
      </div>
```

Before `</body>`

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='assets/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="assets/js/ko-models.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/owl-2-2.3.4/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

My `ko-models.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    apiUrl = "link";
    localizacoes = {
        planosPorLocalizacao: ["Todos", "Rio de Janeiro, RJ", "São Paulo, SP"],
        planosSelecionados: ["Todos"]
    };
    planos = [];
    var vm = null;

    var select = document.getElementById("selected-option");
    select.addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (select.value == "Rio de Janeiro, RJ") {
            apiUrl = "other link";
        } else if (select.value == "São Paulo, SP") {
            apiUrl = "other link";
        } else if (select.value == "Todos") {
            apiUrl = "link";
        }
        console.log(select.value);
        MostraPlanos();
    });

    function MostraPlanos() {
        fetch(apiUrl).then(function(next) {
            next.json().then(function(res) {
                // ko.cleanNode({planos: res});
                res.forEach(el => {
                    el.dependentePreco = el["dependente-preco"];
                    el.precoReal = el["preco"].split(",")[0];
                    el.precoCentavo = el["preco"].split(",")[1];
                });         
                planos = res;
                if(vm == null) {
                    vm = {
                        planos: ko.observable(planos),
                        localizacoes
                    };
                    ko.applyBindings(vm);
                }
                else{
                    vm.planos(planos);
                    vm.gliderCarousel();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    MostraPlanos();

    ko.bindingHandlers.carousel = {
        update: function() {
            $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                margin:10,
                nav:true,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:1
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:3
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:5
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Some observations: **1)** You only need to call `ko.applyBindings(vm)` once. After that you need the update the same instance of view model. [So I suggest converting using a constructor function as viewmodel and using the `new` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589419). So, it's easier for you to `fetch` and update within the view model. You can just do `this.planos(planos)`. **2)** `planos` should be an `observableArray()`. **3)** Adding `addEventListener` is a strict **no no**. You should either use a `subscribe` or `event` binding for `change`.

Comment: @adiga **1)** This completely misses the point, and anyway, `ko.applyBindings(vm)` is only called once. This is why I have an `if..else` in the main function. **2)** `planos` doesn't need to be an observable, only `vm.planos`. **3)** Why is it a "no no"? Where did you get this?

Comment: Sorry I missed the `if(vm == null)` bit. Regarding "planos", I meant converting it to `observableArray` like this: `vm = { planos: ko.observableArray(planos) }`. Regarding the select, use "change" [`event` binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)

Comment: An observable object is created when I do `vm = {planos: ko.observable(planos)}`, right inside the `if`. Otherwise it wouldn't work (and it does - what didn't was the carousel part solved in my answer). On the select, I tried searching for a "knockout" way to do it, but I thought it ended more complex than doing a simple `addEventListener`. Anyway, I just wanted to understand why is it a no, since it's not a bad practice...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem was the way the plugins used to track the carousel. Glider, for instance, was the last one I tried and spent most time at.

From the possible options in [Glider.js](https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/):

> addTrack
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> Whether or not Glider.js should wrap it's children with a
>   'glider-track' .
>
> NOTE: If false, Glider.js will assume that the
>   'glider-track' element has been added manually. All slides must be
>   children of the track element.

Adding `.glider-track` to the outer div (parent of cards) and setting `addTrack: false` in JS solved the issue!